# ASP.net onPageClose event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to find a way of opening a page from a button if its **NOT** already open.

What I have so far is 2 pages.
Default page opens Option page via a button like:-

```
        protected void btnCreateNewWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SharedMethods.Is_Page_Displayed == 0)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Order", "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('Option1.aspx', '', 'fullscreen = yes')</script>");
            SharedMethods.Is_Page_Displayed = 1;
        }
    }
```

Shared Session code:-

```
namespace ns_SharedMethods
{
public class SharedMethods
{

    #region Session
    public static String sIs_Page_Displayed = "Is_Page_Displayed";
    #endregion Session

    public static int Is_Page_Displayed
    {
        get
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[sIs_Page_Displayed] != null)
            {
                return (Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[sIs_Page_Displayed]));
            }
            else
            {
                return (0);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[sIs_Page_Displayed] = value;
        }

    }

    public static String Is_The_Page_Displayed()
    {
        if (Is_Page_Displayed == 1)
        {
            return ("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            return ("NO");
        }
   }
}
```

}

I've tried is using a Session variable as a flag to denote the page is open/closed.

Is it possible to trigger an OnClosePage event in the second Page to set a Session variable "Is_Page_Displayed = 0"?

Any examples is appreciated.

tia

PS I've tried to publish all pages .aspx source code but the formatting was being distorted :(

Comment: You need javascript. I used the broadcast channel. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

Answer (score 0):

Base on the initial code used, add:-

On "Option1.aspx"
Add this to the source:-

```
    <script>
    // Window Event to trigger when the page has closed
    window.onbeforeunload = function (event)
    {
        // C# method called from the Java Script
        PageMethods.SetWebPageClosedSession();           
    }         
</script>
```

And this under the "< body > < form id="form1" runat="server" >"

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Add this to the Option1.aspx.cs:-

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void SetWebPageClosedSession()
    {
        // Method called from the .aspx Script function WebPageClosed()
        SharedMethods.Is_Page_Displayed = 0;
    }
```

So what I've done is use the window.onbeforeunload event, in Option1.aspx, to call a C# method to set a Session variable. The Default.aspx page checks prior to trying to open Option1.aspx